Integrable representations of affine Lie algebra and non-integrable ones
In the book Conformal Field Theory by Di Francesco, Mathieu and Sénéchal, they introduce the integrable highest weight representations of an affine Lie algebra $\widehat{\mathfrak{g}}_k$ associated to a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ at level $k$. The level $k$ and the finite part $\lambda$ of the weight of the HW state $|\widehat{\lambda} \rangle$ should satisfy
$$
(\lambda, \theta) \le k \ , \qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}_+ , \ \lambda_{i = 0, 1, 2, ..., r} \in \mathbb{Z}_+
$$
I wonder, what if I consider $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, but with another "HW" state $|\widehat{\lambda}\rangle$ that $(\lambda, \theta) > k$ (so it would have $\lambda_0 < 0$)? I can imagine acting on it with all the $J^a_{-n}$ to get some representation, which looks like a highest weight representation.
This representation cannot be decomposed into finite dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}{(2)}$ representation. But is this representation reducible or irreducible, and if reducible, is it decomposed into the integrable reps?? How to compute its character?
